# What HTTP verb is appropriate for an api route that restarts an application the server?

Tags: http, semantics

I got asked to do a code review of a very simple one-route web service that when hit would simply restart an application on the system. The developer had coded this up as a POST which strikes me as odd.

Now I realize that this is not really the type of thing that HTTP is all about - you can't even query state - but is there a more appropriate HTTP verb? My intuition is that since this is mostly idempotent and creates no new resources it should be a PUT.

Comment: If the request is browser based, he may have done it to avoid caching the request.  Honestly I dont see why it matters what verb is used for this sort of thing so long as its documented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would also use POST for this, though I can see an argument for PUT. Based on RFC 2616 and my own experience, PUT is usually reserved for updating or replacing a resource. While restarting an application could conceptually fall into that category, to me this seems more like a server-side action, which is typically the purview of a POST request.

Comment: Yeah, it's a POST.

Comment: PUT is useful when you want retry semantics. In this case, I don't think you want middleware retrying the restart command -- could get weird. Also agree that PUT is to create or update data that you want to fetch later, and that's not the case here. Go POST.